# How do I insert/update data into offsite databases that don't have an API available?

Tags: mysql, database, api

I'm trying to figure out how to insert/update data into offsite databases that don't have an API available.  Since they don't have an API, I thought of an approach I can take to insert/update data into their database.

They would first need to build a script and place it in an accessible location on their webserver that I can access via a URL.  They would be required to supply the URL to me. I then can do a cURL POST request to that URL and pass a JSON array of the data that needs to be inserted.  The script on their server would handle the parsing of the JSON array and the insert/update into the database.

I think this should work, but what security issues would I be opening them up to?

Comment: how about emailing the admin of the database and saying : here load this ...

Comment: Because doing it dynamically is instant and accurate.

Comment: It needs to happen constantly through out the day too so that isn't feasible.

Comment: if it was my database, i simply would not let you do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you described is them creating an API. Just because the url invokes a script and isn't written in something like Java or PhP doesn't mean its not an api.

You need to make sure your url is secure so only authorized people can invoke it, and they would probably want to do data validation.

You should let them decide whether that is easier than standing up a more robust/non-script based solution

Comment: ah that makes sense. I didn't think about it as them creating their own API, but I guess it would have the characteristics of a very basic API. Thanks for pointing that out.